# Angular docker page note found

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, angular-cli

I am trying to run a specific version of an angular project on a specific version of node in a docker container.

I build an docker image and run it on a container on a specific port. It tell me than the compile is successfull and then i just have to go on the localhost:[myport] but i get a "Page not found" error.

Here is my docker file :

```
FROM node:10.24 AS ui-build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app/
ADD run.sh ./run.sh

RUN npm install @angular/cli@7.3.9 && npm install
RUN chmod 777 ./run.sh


EXPOSE 9004

# using the script 'run.sh' to run the app
# this script run the app depending on his name
CMD ./run.sh particulier
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4ONt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRHAA.png)

As you can see in those image my container is running well, it compiles my node module inside the container and tell me to go on localhost:9004 to see my app

But I get an Page not found error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz95Q.png)

Here my docker run command : `docker run -it -p  9004:4200 --name hiero_particulierv6.2 angular-node-image-v6`

**EDIT**
I changed the dockerfile by getting out the `EXPOSE 9004` code.

Because, as you can see in the CMD part, I call a script **run.sh**, and this script run the app on different port depending on the name :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit on error
set -o errexit

curdir=$(pwd)

app=""
port=0
extra=""

if [ "$1" = "hiero" ]; then
  app="hiero"
  port="9000"
  # extra="--proxy-config ./dev_config/app.proxy.conf.js"
elif [ "$1" = "admin" ]; then
  app="admin"
  port="9001"
elif [ "$1" = "pdf" ]; then
  app="pdf"
  port="9002"
  elif [ "$1" = "pro" ]; then
  app="pro"
  port="9003"
  elif [ "$1" = "particulier" ]; then
  app="particulier"
  port="9004"
else
  echo "Unknown app: $1"
  echo "Try: ./run.sh hiero"
fi

if [ ! -z "$app" ]; then
  ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --aot --project $app --port $port $extra
fi
```

Comment: Change localhost to your Docker container IP address!

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your `docker run` command, so we can see it, please?

Comment: Are you sure your angular project is running on port 9004, and not on the default port 4200 for angular? In that case expose on port your angular project is using. You can also run docker run with -p externport:internalport (-p 9004:4200). In that case you can access with port 9004 the 4200 inside your container.

Comment: i edit the post to awse your question by explaining more